# how to convert pyspark data frame to json list without double quotes for numbers and extra // for date columns

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, pyspark

I am trying to to convert pyspark data frame to json list which i need to pass the json values to api, when am trying to convert all json values populating with "" like valuue =12 but when converting its coming like value ="12" and date with 3\/7\/2022 how can i avoid these extra \ and double quotes.

am using below code:

```
loan = loan_detail_df.toPandas()
results = loan.to_json(orient='records')
```

My output is :

```
[{"Lead_Number":"","Number":"123456","user1_DOB":"3\/20\/1943""ExpectedRate":"0"}]
```

My desired output :

```
{"Lead_Number":'',"Number":123456,"user1_DOB":"3/20/1943""ExpectedRate":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following syntax:

```
df.write.json(<storage path>)
```

The output will look like this if the `date` column is in `DateType()` format:

```
{"number":1,"date":"2021-03-22"}
```

If the `date` column is in `StringType()` format with `/` as the separator between date components, the output will be:

```
{"number":1,"date":"2022/03/12"}
```

**To get the json string values to write out to api**
you can use the pyspark.sql.functions.to_json() transformation.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, '2022/03/12')  
], ['number', 'date'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('json_value', f.to_json(f.struct(f.col('number'), f.col('date'))))
)

print(df.collect()[0]['json_value'])
```

And the output is:

```
{"number":1,"date":"2022/03/12"}
```

Comment: I dont need to save the json file, on the fly need to load into body of API file with required data